# String Serialization in utf-8 using Node Buffer

Tags: sql, node.js, utf-8, hex, buffer

I have a sql database storing a blob using `unhex('6BFD3D0AFDFD4E01FDFD67703A34757F')`.

The server retrieves the blob and stores it in a Node Buffer as `<Buffer 6b 8a 3d 0a 9b eb 4e 01 96 a6 67 70 3a 34 75 7f>`.

The server serializes the buffer and send it to the client using `buffer.toString()` which defaults to `utf8` encoding.

The client receives and deserializes the buffer using `Buffer.from(buffer, 'utf8')`, which results in `<Buffer 6b ef bf bd 3d 0a ef bf bd ef bf bd 4e 01 ef bf bd ef bf bd 67 70 3a 34 75 7f>` and then if I convert it back to hex using `.toString('hex')` I get `6BEFBFBD3D0AEFBFBDEFBFBD4E01EFBFBDEFBFBD67703A34757F`.

**So to sum it all up**, if I do:

```
let startHex = "6BFD3D0AFDFD4E01FDFD67703A34757F"
let buffer = Buffer.from(hex, 'hex')
let endHex = Buffer.from(buffer.toString()).toString('hex').toUpperCase())
console.log(endHex)
```

The output is:

```
6BEFBFBD3D0AEFBFBDEFBFBD4E01EFBFBDEFBFBD67703A34757F
```

**My question** is why is `startHex` and `endHex` different? They aren't just different. They look similar except the `endHex` has extra characters. I know I get the correct output if I serialize the buffer between the server and the client using `base64` or `binary`, but for my project it is easier if the client is able to figure out `startHex` given the serialized buffer using `utf8`. The reason is that I do not have access to the inner workings of the server which actually calls `buffer.toString()` before sending to the client, so I cannot change the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid UTF-8 characters in your original input. The invalid UTF-8 replacement character has bytes EFBFBD and you can see that several times in the output.